# xpath conditional match possible?

Tags: xpath

Ok basically I'm trying to use XPath to find a match "given a condition."  basically, with the following xml:

```
 <stuff1>
   <stuff2>abc</stuff2>
 </stuff1>
 <stuff3>
   <stuff4>abc</stuff4>
   <stuff5>true</stuff5>
 </stuff3>
 <stuff3>
   <stuff4>abc</stuff4>
   <stuff5>false</stuff5>
   <stuff6>extra stuff</stuff6>
 </stuff3>
```

what I'd like to do is select stuff1's that match stuff3's based on stuff2==stuff4, but also where the stuff3's have a "stuff5" value of false, but not true.

I know `//stuff1[stuff2/text()=../stuff3/stuff4/text()]` will select me the stuff1's that match the stuff3's, but how do I specify that the stuff3's must have a stuff5 value of false?  Sorry if this elementary or answered elsewhere, random searching didn't seem to reveal the answer easily.
Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're almost there, if you want to only match `stuff3` elements with a `stuff5` value of false, you can do that by adding the predicate `[stuff5/text()="false"]`to the `stuff3` match.

The complete XPath should look something like the following:

`//stuff1[stuff2/text()=../stuff3[stuff5/text()="false"]/stuff4/text()]`

Comment: awesome thank you.  I also wonder if it's possible to say...include the matched stuff3's in the node output but if you don't know off hand don't worry about it.

Comment: @rogerdpack, Could you, please, rephrase? I don't understand what exactly elements you want to select.

Comment: ok, I updated the original question, basically it's "given the xpath in this answer, how could I also stuff6/extra stuff returned. If that makes sense anyhow :)